# vuetify & nuxt : how to switch vuetify components locale when current locale switched?

Tags: internationalization, nuxt.js, vuetify.js, vue-i18n

for switch between locales i have made a plugin
and in it

```js
// plugins/i18n

export default function({ app }) {
  app.i18n.onLanguageSwitched = (oldLocale, newLocale) => {
    console.log(oldLocale, newLocale)
    app.vuetify.lang.current = newLocale
    console.log(app)
  }
}
```

but when i switch language , components locale dont change and i get this error
[image]

and this is nuxt config

```js
// nuxt config
import en from 'vuetify/src/locale/en.ts'
import de from 'vuetify/src/locale/de.ts'

  vuetify: {
    treeShake: true,
    customVariables: ['~/assets/styles/setting/_variables.scss'],
  
    lang: {
      locales: {
        de,
        en
      },
      current: 'de'
     
    },

},
```

how do i change vuetify component locale when current locale changed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found the solution
i changed thath plugin like this
and it woks.

```js
export default function({ app }) {

  app.vuetify.framework.lang.current =  app.i18n.locale
  app.i18n.onLanguageSwitched = (ـ, newLocale) => {
    app.vuetify.framework.lang.current = newLocale
  }
}
```